# Adjective for a neatness control freak about only few things that bother the person and not in others

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I have a family member in my house. He is a neatness control freak but the difference is he is neatness control freak about few things that bother him and not at all neatness bothered about a lot of other things that matter to hygiene of the house members.

Background
The neatness he is freaked about is associated with things he was tormented about in his childhood by his parents and then there are those which are obvious to others but he seems careless about. This freakishness seem to come about due to blind disciplining and not do to morality.

If i have to use an adjective, what is the word/phrase i can use

________ neatness control freak.

Describing his freakishness in something and not in others. I don't want to use 'random' because by now the controlling does not seem random, it is quite systematically predicable.

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Answer (score -2):

[Pettifogger or pettifogging](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pettifogger#English) (Wiktionary): Someone who quibbles over trivia, and raises petty, annoying objections and sophistry.
An unscrupulous or unethical lawyer, especially one of lesser skill.

[Pedantic](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pedantic) (Collins Dictionary) adjective If you think someone is pedantic, you mean that they are too concerned with unimportant details or traditional rules, especially in connection with academic subjects.

Two-word combinations can also be used, such as "picky perfectionist" or "picky fusser" etc.

Comment: Negative voter, kindly tell why is the answer not useful.

Comment: I didn't downvote but neither seems to capture what the OP is trying to express. Firstly, the fact that he's only bothered about a few things. Pedantic suggests someone who's obsessed over every minor trivial thing. Both words suggest being quarrelsome rather than controlling which seems to be what the OP wants. Pettifogging suggests officialdom or lawyering. The question is rather vague, and with comments disabled it's impossible to get clarification, so this may be as good as we get, but I don't think it's really what is wanted.

Comment: Picky perfectionist with a domineering attitude like Trump? Trumplike? Trumplet?